# Check if the player is moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't really like checking it with the velocity and other physics and anyway it doesn't seem to work, saving the position in Vector3 object in the end of the Update(current loop) and then comparing it with current position(in next loop) doesn't work as it holds the same numbers as current position. I've also tried using FixedUpdate instead of Update but it was no good either. I did try writing `curr_pos = new Vector3(transform.position.x...)` and it got me the same numbers for last and current position aswell and i also tried comparing it to just current position without any variables

I also tried doing it as simple as using `Input.GetKey("w")` or  `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.up)`

```
public Vector3 prev_pos, curr_pos;
void Update(){
    prev_pos = this.transform.position;
    ...
    if(prev_pos != curr_pos){
            bool moving = true;
        }
        else{
            bool moving = false;
        }
        if(sprinting && !crouching && moving){
            speed = sprint_speed;
    }
    curr_pos = prev_pos;
}
```

I have a character controller on my player and am moving it with this controller

```
CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
if(controller.isGrounded) {
            moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
            moveDirection *= speed;
            if(Input.GetButton ("Jump")){
                moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
            }
}
```

Comment: The reason velocity isn’t working is because it’s not using physics to move. You could just check if after picking up horizontal/vertical if either are not 0 and declare moving or not

Comment: It looks like your code should work (although I think you swapped the names `prev_pos` and `curr_pos` and declared `bool moving` in the wrong scope). Make sure that this script is attached to the player GameObject (the same one that the CharacterController is on).

Comment: @RAstra I've made sure it does, because all of my moving script lies there and my character is moving okay while this moving check just doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem you have to correct your algorithm. At the bottom is a simpler example that calculates the location of the previous position at the end of each frame.

```cs
public Vector3 prev_pos;
void Update(){

    var moving = prev_pos != transform.position;
    
    if(moving)
    {
        // when moving..
    }
    prev_pos = transform.position;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work either



`var moving = prev_pos != transform.position;
        if(sprinting && !crouching && moving){
            speed = sprint_speed;
            stamina = Mathf.Clamp(stamina - (10*Time.deltaTime), 0.0f, max_stamina);
        }
prev_pos = transform.position;`

The prev_pos variable still contains the same number as my current transform.position does